# span and strong tags are not working in jsdom

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, jsdom, draftjs

I am new to jsdom and I just want to convert html tags to json using draft js in node services.
I got jsdom for conversion, so I worked on that so normal tags are working fine but some tags are not working.
Here is my code.

```
    const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
    const { window } = new JSDOM();
    const { document } = (new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html>`)).window;
    global.document = document;
    global.navigator = window.navigator
    global.HTMLElement = window.HTMLElement
    const djs = require('draft-js')
    const html = '<p>Hey this <span>editor</span> rocks </p>';
    const json=djs.convertToRaw(djs.ContentState.createFromBlockArray(djs.convertFromHTML(html)))
    console.log("Hello",json);
    var jQuery = require('jquery')(window);
```

It is giving me error

```
node:22923) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: Node is not defined
    at isElement (/home/ec2-user/environment/info-data-migration/node_modules/draft-js/lib/isElement.js:18:28)
    at isHTMLImageElement (/home/ec2-user/environment/info-data-migration/node_modules/draft-js/lib/isHTMLImageElement.js:20:10)
    at isValidImage (/home/ec2-user/environment/info-data-migration/node_modules/draft-js/lib/convertFromHTMLToContentBlocks.js:184:8)
    at ContentBlocksBuilder._toBlockConfigs (/home/ec2-user/environment/info-data-migration/node_modules/draft-js/lib/convertFromHTMLToContentBlocks.js:490:11)
    at ContentBlocksBuilder._toBlockConfigs (/home/ec2-user/environment/info-data-migration/node_modules/draft-js/lib/convertFromHTMLToContentBlocks.js:432:52)
    at ContentBlocksBuilder.addDOMNode (/home/ec2-user/environment/info-data-migration/node_modules/draft-js/lib/convertFromHTMLToContentBlocks.js:333:82)
    at Object.convertFromHTMLToContentBlocks [as convertFromHTML] (/home/ec2-user/environment/info-data-migration/node_modules/draft-js/lib/convertFromHTMLToContentBlocks.js:791:63)
    at Object.rawFromHTML (/home/ec2-user/environment/info-data-migration/controller/jsontoHTMLConverter.js:170:24)
    at Object.getCandidateTableData (/home/ec2-user/environment/info-data-migration/controller/candidate_fullfile.js:31:119)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:22923) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:22923) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

fun fact code is working without span tags.

```
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
    const { window } = new JSDOM();
    const { document } = (new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html>`)).window;
    global.document = document;
    global.navigator = window.navigator
    global.HTMLElement = window.HTMLElement
    const djs = require('draft-js')
    const html = '<p>Hey this rocks </p>';
    const json=djs.convertToRaw(djs.ContentState.createFromBlockArray(djs.convertFromHTML(html)))
    console.log("Hello",json);
    var jQuery = require('jquery')(window);
```

I need to convert html data to json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're adding browser objects to node's `global`, you also need to add the `Node` object like so:

```
// [...]
global.HTMLElement = window.HTMLElement
global.Node = window.Node // <== Add this
// [...]
```

This is because the nested `<span>` tag creates text nodes inside the `<p>` tag and Draft.js is parsing these.

I don't know the context of your code but if you simply have an HTML string that you'd like to convert to JSON/JS objects, it might be easier to use something like [xml2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js) instead:

```
const util = require('util');
const parseString = util.promisify(require('xml2js').parseString); // `promisify` makes it possible to use `async/await`

(async function(){
    const obj = await parseString('<p>Hey this <span>editor</span> rocks </p>');
    console.log(obj); // { p: { _: 'Hey this  rocks ', span: [ 'editor' ] } }
}());
```